# Pass image id to php mysql query via jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to pass image id to mysql query.

For that, i have done these coding. But it results in Undefined index x: I referenced many stackoverflow answers. But nothing is working.

```
echo "<img src=http://localhost/ss/img/".$p['path']." id=".$p['album_id']." class='img-responsive' alt='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg1'>";

if(isset($_GET['x'])) { echo $_GET['x']'; } 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".g2 img").click(function() {
                var albumID = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(albumID);  //working fine, getting id
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'index.php',
                    //data: x: "albumID",           
                    data: x: albumID,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                       alert("success!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

What is the wrong which i'm doing? Please help me.

Comment: you have a mistake with  { echo $_GET['x']'; } with the quotation

Comment: After removing also, it shows Notice: Undefined index: x, Is there any other method to pass clicked image id to php

Comment: try the `get` format i have mentioned and reply

Answer (score 5):

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])) { echo $_GET['x']'; }
```

replace with

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])) { echo $_GET['x']; }
```

extra ' was there

if the issue is still there check your url that should be somthing like this

```
 index.php?x=sometext
```

Comment: After removing also, it shows Notice: Undefined index: x, Is there any other method to pass clicked image id to php

Comment: yes, i can pass clicked image id to url as index.php?x=13

Answer (score 0):

need not use it like that just make a ajax call and place the data in whatever div you want

using `document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML=data;`

try

```
$('body').on('change','.g2 img',function() {    //works for ajax loaded contents
    var albumID = $(this).attr('id');

    var formid  =   new FormData();

    formid.append('albumID ',albumID );

    $.ajax({            

                    url         :   'index.php',
                    dataType    :   'text',
                    cache       :   false,
                    contentType :   false,
                    processData :   false,
                    data        :   formid,        
                    type        :   'post',
                    success     :   function(data){     
                                alert(result);                     

                                //document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=data;

                    }
            });
 }
```

**just try using**

```
url: 'index.php?x='+albumID,
```

change your href you have mentioned to

`<a href="/test.php?abid=<?php echo $id;?>">`
this should work

dynamic sql query??

use something like `$str  =  "insert into table values('".value1."',  '".value2."',  '".value3."')"`

Comment: Yes, i'm getting ids, but i need to pass dynamically in mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost/ss/img/".$p['path']." id=".$p['album_id']." class='img-responsive' alt='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg1'>";

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])) { 
    echo $_GET['x']; 
} 
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".g2").click(function() {
                var albumID = $('.img-responsive').attr('id');
                alert(albumID);  //working fine, getting id
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'index.php',
                    //data: x: "albumID",           
                    data: {x: albumID},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                       alert("success!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: what the issue you face,can you explain it?